# Can the verb "sandwich" be used in an active voice?

Tags: verbs

Longman Online Dictionary takes the following example sentence to explain the verb "sandwich":

> [A layer of transparent material is sandwiched between the pieces of
>   glass.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sandwich)

Is it possible to rewrite this as follows?:

> The pieces of glass sandwich a layer of transparent material.

Comment: Yes. See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sandwich

Answer (score 1):

Yes the verb sandwich can be used in the active voice.

The link shared by Ronald Sole includes the example

> Two goals from Eden Hazard sandwiched a Victor Moses strike.

So you could say

> The pieces of glass sandwich a layer of transparent material.